# command line comparison (e.g. diff) ignoring non-whitespace first character of each line while keeping displaying it in output

Tags: bash, command-line, diff, pandoc

pandoc prints the available extensions for each format with a leading `+` or `-` (depending on whether the extension is enabled or disabled). So for example

```
$ pandoc --list-extensions=markdown
-abbreviations
+all_symbols_escapable
-angle_brackets_escapable
+auto_identifiers
-autolink_bare_uris
+backtick_code_blocks
...
```

In order to diff two format's available extensions, I simply do (bash)

```
$ diff -y <(pandoc --list-extensions=markdown | tr -d '+-') <(pandoc --list-extensions=commonmark | tr -d '+-')
abbreviations                                                 <
all_symbols_escapable                                           all_symbols_escapable
angle_brackets_escapable                                      | ascii_identifiers
auto_identifiers                                                auto_identifiers
autolink_bare_uris                                              autolink_bare_uris
backtick_code_blocks                                            backtick_code_blocks
blank_before_blockquote                                       <
blank_before_header                                           <
```

In the output I'd like to keep the leading `+` or `-`, that is for example

```
+abbreviations                                                 <
+all_symbols_escapable                                           -all_symbols_escapable
-angle_brackets_escapable                                      | -ascii_identifiers
+auto_identifiers                                                -auto_identifiers
-autolink_bare_uris                                              -autolink_bare_uris
+backtick_code_blocks                                            -backtick_code_blocks
+blank_before_blockquote                                       <
+blank_before_header                                           <
```

Please notice that this is different from running

```
$ diff -y <(pandoc --list-extensions=markdown) <(pandoc --list-extensions=commonmark)
-abbreviations                                                | -all_symbols_escapable
+all_symbols_escapable                                        | -ascii_identifiers
-angle_brackets_escapable                                     | -auto_identifiers
+auto_identifiers                                             <
-autolink_bare_uris                                             -autolink_bare_uris
+backtick_code_blocks                                         | -backtick_code_blocks
+blank_before_blockquote                                      <
+blank_before_header                                          <
```

What's the simplest way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Not really a nice solution, but you don't have an answer yet and this was the best I could think of to keep the output the same as you intended

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t markdown < <(pandoc --list-extensions=markdown)
commonmark="$(pandoc --list-extensions=commonmark)"
out=(); i=0
while read -r line; do
    change="$(echo "${line}" | grep -Eo '<|\|')" || change=' ' && line="$(echo "${line}" | awk '{print $NF}')"
    com="$(echo "${commonmark}" | grep "${line}")"
    out+=("${markdown[i]},${change} ${com}"); ((i++))
done < <(diff -y <(printf '%s\n' "${markdown[@]}" | tr -d '+-') <(echo "${commonmark}" | tr -d '+-'))
printf '%s\n' "${out[@]}" | column -t -s ','
```

outputs

```
-abbreviations                      < 
+all_symbols_escapable                -all_symbols_escapable
-angle_brackets_escapable           | -ascii_identifiers
+auto_identifiers                     -auto_identifiers
-gfm_auto_identifiers               
-autolink_bare_uris                   -autolink_bare_uris
+backtick_code_blocks                 -backtick_code_blocks
+blank_before_blockquote            < 
+blank_before_header                < 
+bracketed_spans                    < 
+citations                          < 
-compact_definition_lists           < 
+definition_lists                   < 
-east_asian_line_breaks               -east_asian_line_breaks
-emoji                                -emoji
...
```

Comment: thanks. I'm also going to post my solution which I don't like very much. Anyway I believe there is an easier way to do this, maybe with `xargs`... but I'm not in very good shape with bash right now :D

Answer (score 1):

My own attempt is the following

```
#!/bin/bash

format1="$1"
format2="$2"

leftExtPattern=$(sed -E 's/^(\+|-)/\1\^/g' <(pandoc --list-extensions=$1 | tr -d '\r') )
rightExtPattern=$(sed -E 's/$/\$/g' <(pandoc --list-extensions=$2 | tr -d '\r') )

diffExtensions=$(diff -y -t --strip-trailing-cr \
  <(echo "$leftExtPattern" | tr -d '^+-') \
  <(echo "$rightExtPattern" | tr -d '$+-'))

while read -r pattern; do
  diffExtensions=$(echo "$diffExtensions" | sed -E "s/\b(${pattern:1})\b/${pattern:0:1}\1/g")
done <<<"$leftExtPattern"$'\n'"$rightExtPattern"
echo "$diffExtensions"
```

I believe there is a much more elegant and compact way to do this, maybe with `xargs`...